# C++ static class member, who cleans up the mess?

Tags: c++, memory

I was wondering which part of my code will free a dynamically allocated, but static class member when this is not needed anymore. See the following code: `classPrinter` is shared among all `A`-objects and created when the first instance of class `A` will be created. Just to be sure:  the `classPrinter`-object will automatically be destructed when exiting my program, right?

**a.h**

```
class A {
static B* classPrinter;
}
```

**a.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"
B A::classPrinter = new B();

A::A() { ...}
```

Comment: Smart pointers are good for this kind of thing, at least if you really need dynamic allocation (see [sbi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8578256/10077).

Comment: Ack.... static pointer == evil.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Just to be sure:  the `somePrinter`-object will automatically be destructed when exiting my program, right?

Since this is C++, the answer is "No." For everything allocated with `new` the corresponding `delete` must be called. If that doesn't happen, the object leaks. But why allocate this dynamically at all? This

```
class A {
  static B classPrinter;
}

B A::classPrinter;
```

behaves like your code, except that `classPrinter` will be destructed at the end of the program.

However, you write that

> `classPrinter` is shared among all A-objects and created when the first instance of class `A` will be created.

The code in your question doesn't do this. *If* you want to do this, do something like this:

```
class A {
  static std::shared_ptr<B> classPrinter;
}

std::shared_ptr<B> A::classPrinter;

A::A()
{
  if(!classPrinter)
    classPrinter.reset(new B());
}
```

The smart pointer will make sure that the object gets deleted.

Comment: "is shared among all A-objects and created when the first instance of class A will be created"

Comment: @pezcode: I suppose you refer to "created when the first instance of class A will be created." I read that, but the code in the question does the same as my code (except for leaking, of course).

Comment: may be new operator is overloaded, i think its not a case, but in theory its possible.

Comment: Minor nit. After making classPrinter an object instead of a pointer, you say "this behaves like your code, except that classPrinter will be deleted at the end of the program." No, it won't be deleted, as it isn't a pointer, and no `delete` is called, but it will be destroyed (its destructor will run).

Comment: @Brian: Thanks, you're right. I have changed "deleted" to "destructed".

Comment: It's _probably_ the same, but you can't know what weird side effects B::B() might have. Anyway, it's not our job to guess about that.

Comment: Shouldn't this rather be a `unique_ptr`? I mean, it's the same in all instances.

Comment: @sbi, +1, because you write an answer, and was very explicit about the object deallocation process. My code example is not as explicit as yours ;-)

Answer (score 10):

No, objects created using `new` are never automatically deleted. You should always provide a matching `delete` to prevent memory leaks.

In this case, the simplest solution would be to have a static object, rather than a static pointer to a dynamic object - there is no reason at all for the extra level of indirection.

```
// header file
class A {
    static B classPrinter;
};

// source file
B A::classPrinter;
```

or if you want to delay the construction until the object is needed (and avoid potential problems if static objects in other translation units need to access it from their constructors):

```
class A {
    static B & classPrinter() {
        static B instance;
        return instance;
    }
};
```

In other situations, when you actually need dynamic allocation, you should always manage the dynamic object using smart pointers or other [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) objects.

Comment: That local static is a nice trick I forgot to mention. `+1` from me.

Answer (score 3):

The destructor of the object of which `A::classPrinter` points to will not be called.

If you think about it's nothing else but logic; where is the matching `delete`-statement that, in normal cases, would call the dtor of the object?

The memory occupied will be flagged as free again and returned to the system, at least in all modern such.

Comment: @sbi I'm not sure if I had the chance to edit my post before or after your comment, but I did change the wording so it should be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If `A::classPrinter` is shared amongst multiple members, maybe use std::shared_ptr instead of a raw pointer? It will be automatically deleted after all references to it are gone.

But yes, the memory will be reclaimed after the program exits, at least on all OS's I can think of...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some wrapper or use something like shared_ptr to  guarantee dtor call.

Answer (score 0):

Static (as far as static member variable) inherently means, always exists.

If you make a static pointer, you simply cannot deallocate at a point that makes sense. You need more context.

If you want shared data that exists only while you have instances of static member owner class, then you need a static counter. Allocate a new static value whenever you create an instance and counter == 0. Deallocate the current static value whenever you delete the last instance of the owner class.

Otherwise, you'll have to dip into things like shared or smart pointers to deallocate, but even then you run into problems. If the smart pointer sees no more references and deallocates, it may do so too early. If it's in the deallocated state, then what does that mean when you need the information again. Do you allocate a new static value?

If the static member needs to always exist whether you have an instance of the owner class or not, you should consider changing the pointer into a reference or instance instead.